# How to do pandas 2D cut

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, binning

I'm familiar with pandas cut(), and am looking for an efficient way to do it in 2 dimension.

Background: I have two data frames. df_data consist of X and Y coordinates, while df_box consist of lower-left X, lower-left Y, upper-left X, upper-right Y of regions of interest, and their respective names. I would like to label the coordinates in df_data according to their region.

Assumption: (1) For first pass, assuming that the regions in df_box are mutually exclusive is OK.

I wrote the following code which is super fast (speed is important since I'm dealing with millions of rows in each data frame). However, it has a drawback: if we have regions that are not uniformly spaced, then this method doesn't work. [See illustration of what works and what doesn't here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CmaU.png)

```
def label_by_bbox2(df_in, col_x, col_y, df_bbox, col_llx, col_lly, col_urx, col_ury, col_label, dropNoMatch=False):
    ''' assumes mutually exclusive bounding boxes, and there's only one pair of lattice constant.
    Labels are treated as strings.  '''

    df_bbox_now = df_bbox[[col_llx, col_lly, col_urx, col_ury, col_label]]
    df_bbox_now = df_bbox_now.drop_duplicates(subset=[col_llx, col_lly, col_urx, col_ury])

    # NOTE: because of our assumption of mutually exclusive bbox, and only one pair of lattice constant,
    # it is enough to evaluate llx and lly

    # --- llx ---
    bin_now = df_bbox.sort_values(col_llx)[col_llx].drop_duplicates()
    binlabel_now = bin_now[ : len(bin_now)-1 ]  # drop last element
    df_in[col_x] = df_in[col_x].astype(float)
    df_in['llx'] = pd.cut( df_in[col_x], bin_now, labels=binlabel_now).astype(float)
    #df_in['llx2'] = pd.cut( df_in[col_x], bin_now)

    # --- lly ---
    bin_now = df_bbox.sort_values(col_lly)[col_lly].drop_duplicates()
    binlabel_now = bin_now[ : len(bin_now)-1 ]  # drop last element
    df_in[col_y] = df_in[col_y].astype(float)
    df_in['lly'] = pd.cut( df_in[col_y], bin_now, labels=binlabel_now).astype(float)

    # --- update the table with labels ---
    df_in = df_in.set_index([col_llx, col_lly])
    df_bbox_now = df_bbox_now.set_index([col_llx, col_lly])

    df_in[col_label] = df_bbox_now[col_label]
    df_in = df_in.reset_index(drop=True)
    df_in[col_label] = df_in[col_label].astype(str)

    # --- delete entries that have no match ---
    if dropNoMatch:
        df_in = df_in[ df_in[col_label]!='nan' ]
        df_in = df_in.reset_index(drop=True)

    return df_in
```

Loosely speaking, I'm looking for some kind of cut() that works on multi-index. Does anyone have thoughts on how to tackle the cases where the regions are not uniformly spaced while not significantly sacrifice computation speed? I don't mind working with numpy, for example.

Thanks.